# Max limit for a single form field?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I am running into a randomly occuring issue, and it looks like either there is a bug in the third party control we are using or the size of a form field is limited. I've seen there is a limit in classic asp http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN;q273482 but is there a limit in .net?

I believe if we reached the max limit setting on the entire post body that asp.net would generate an error instead of truncating the form field. I know most likely this an error in the third party control but I want to vette all other possible options. Essentially what is occuring is they are posting a url encoded xml msg in the body and the xml is getting truncated sometimes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check to see that there isn't a limit in the database table or stored procedure.  if there isn't a limit there then maybe the parameter variable is declared with a limit in the .net code.  the default maxRequestLength set in the machine.config is 4096 which should accommodate any posting in a form

there shouldn't be any limits because i have projects where people post upwards of 200,000 characters to a single form field.

Comment: The database and stored procs have no bearing here. This control is trying to load its state from the Xml, which is getting truncated.good to know there is no limit on the field

Comment: where are you storing the XML? in a file or in a database field?

Comment: neither the xml is being generated on the client by the third party control and posted in a form field to the server, when it gets to the server it fails to load.

Comment: i would definitely contact the 3rd party vendor.  this is not a limitation of ASP.NET

Comment: i have, I've always had better luck with their support when I activley investigate issues as well;-)